# How to wait for supervisorctl to finish reloading?

Tags: bash, supervisord

I started to use `supervisorctl reload` instead of `supervisorctl restart myprocess` because `reload` does not cause outage whereas `restart` does.

However, calling `supervisorctl status` directly after `supervisorctl reload` fails since the system is still reloading.
In my deployment script I would still like to confirm that supervisor reloaded successfully so I need to wait.
How can I wait for `supervisor reload` to finish in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the quick and dirty solution to these situations is to use an `until` loop to check for something that `myprocess` does to confirm that everything is ready.

Let's assume `myprocess` opens a socket on port 80 after all the pre-flight checks are successful, then using `netcat` to try connecting to port 80 should do the trick:

```
supervisorctl reload myprocess

until nc -z somehost 80 &> /dev/null
do
  sleep 1
done

some other commands
```